# Passing arguments to apply

Tags: python, python-polars

In Pandas, I currently use groupby apply this way (this is a MRE only):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class ApplyFunction:
    def Close(df, *args):
        return pd.DataFrame(df['Close'] * args[0])

class Placeholder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ind = ApplyFunction.Close
        self.args = [2]
call = Placeholder()

date_range = np.arange(np.datetime64("2020-01-01"), np.datetime64("2020-01-03"), np.timedelta64(1, "D"))
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['AAA', 'BBB'], date_range], names=['Symbol','Date'])
df = pd.DataFrame({"Close": [8,9,10,11]}, idx, ['Close'])

df["Result"] = df.groupby("Symbol", group_keys=False).apply(*[call.ind, *call.args])

>>                    Close  Result
>> Symbol Date                     
>> AAA    2020-01-01      8      16
>>        2020-01-02      9      18
>> BBB    2020-01-01     10      20
>>        2020-01-02     11      22
```

While I can call the ApplyFunction in polars, I cannot figure out how to pass arguments in a similar fashion:

```
import polars as pl

class ApplyFunction:
    def Close(df, *args):
        return pl.DataFrame(df['Close'])

df = pl.from_pandas(df.reset_index(drop=False))
df = df.with_columns(
        df.groupby("Symbol", maintain_order=True).apply(
            function=call.ind,
        )
     )

shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬─────────────────────┬───────┐
│ Symbol ┆ Date                ┆ Close │
│ ---    ┆ ---                 ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ datetime[ns]        ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ AAA    ┆ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 8     │
│ AAA    ┆ 2020-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 9     │
│ BBB    ┆ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 10    │
│ BBB    ┆ 2020-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 11    │
└────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┘
```

This is what I'd like to use but it obviously fails:

```
df = df.with_columns(
        df.groupby("Symbol", maintain_order=True).apply(
            function=*[call.ind, *call.args],
        )
     )

>> TypeError: GroupBy.apply() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to "wrap" the function? e.g. `function=lambda group: call.ind(group, *call.args))`

Comment: Thank you. This does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @jqurious struggling to add the result back into the original df, how would I go about this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? What you currently have should work.

Comment: In Pandas it's just creating a new column "Result" in my example, the resulting frame should have that column which is multiplied by two. TLDR: I'd just like to get the polars output to be identical to that of Pandas in my MRE.

Comment: Your polars version does the same for me: https://bpa.st/A5P3O - Also note the last example - if this is what you're actually trying to do - you can do it in regular polars expressions without using `.apply`. Using `.apply` should be considered as a last resort as it is "slow".

Comment: It's an in place substitution as of now. The ApplyFunction can be one of many numba functions which is a transplant from the pandas version. If you don't mind, can you take a look at the Pandas example above. I can do inplace column modification just fine but I'd like to create a new column called 'Result' from the new values.

Comment: You need to name the column you're returning from `ApplyFunction` e.g. `pl.DataFrame(df['Close'] * args[0], schema=["Result"])` - the problem is it's using the name `Close` so it's overwriting the current column.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can do this using `pipe` with Polars expressions instead of the apply function.

Here is an example:

```
def close(close_number, *args):
    return close_number * args[0]

df_pl.with_columns(
    Result = pl.col('Close').pipe(lambda x: close(x, 2))
)

shape: (4, 4)
┌────────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬────────┐
│ Symbol ┆ Date                ┆ Close ┆ Result │
│ ---    ┆ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ str    ┆ datetime[ns]        ┆ i64   ┆ i64    │
╞════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ AAA    ┆ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 8     ┆ 16     │
│ AAA    ┆ 2020-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 9     ┆ 18     │
│ BBB    ┆ 2020-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 10    ┆ 20     │
│ BBB    ┆ 2020-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 11    ┆ 22     │
└────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴────────┘
```

Is this what you are looking to do?

Comment: Thanks. I'd need to keep the original structure though, the example is just a MRE and the production code structure cannot be changed (Placeholder and ApplyFunction should be used).

Comment: Hi @misantroop, I modified the example with *args to show how you could deal with multiple arguments. Let me know if this is what you need

Comment: This works well for passing arguments but not the groupby which is necessary. This is financial data, each group passed to the 'close' function would be a Symbol from that column.

Comment: @misantroop : understood. It looks like the solution from jqurious is working. If in the future you want to look into replacing the apply with Polars expressions to make it efficient, you can share about it . A new question would be best in that case